# My codes are they distributed in spark with Jupyter notebook Kernel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I need help because I don't know if the Jupyter notebook Kernel are usable in a Spark cluster.

In my local Spark I use this and I don't have problems.

I am using this Kernel for PySpark : https://github.com/Anchormen/pyspark-jupyter-kernels

I am using a Standalone Spark cluster with three nodes without Yarn.

Best regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to your spark cluster standalone using the master IP with the python kernel.

```
import pyspark 
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master='spark://<public-ip>:7077', appName='<your_app_name>')
```

References

- [How to connect Jupyter Notebook to remote spark clusters](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-connect-jupyter-notebook-to-remote-spark-clusters-and-run-spark-jobs-every-day-2c5a0c1b61df)
- [Set up an Apache Spark cluster and integrate with Jupyter Notebook](https://davidadrian.cc/how-to-spark-cluster-jupyter/)
- [Deploy Application from Jupyter Lab to a Spark Standalone Cluster](https://dasiyql.medium.com/deploy-application-from-jupyter-lab-to-a-spark-standalone-cluster-d2dcd596fbb8)

Comment: Thx Carlos for your Answer. This method work with findspark(). You know Apache Toree ? You know if I can define my cluster master ? Or Toree work only in local ?

Comment: I have never worked with Apache Toree, but checking out the documentation I found how to configure the [spark master](https://toree.apache.org/docs/current/user/installation#configuring-spark).